# unarchive/extract/unpack/disassemble pdf

Tags: pdf, archiving

I know they have a very particular structure and such, but there are soft that have the ability to extract some parts of it. So is there something like an archive reader that can read through PDF like we can read through a Word file? I repeat myself, I know that's not an archive, but I know it archive full-fledged picture files for example, and maybe the equivalent for text and such. I don't search for a soft that extract certain type of data of it. But more like an archive reader that display all what it contains, so we can choose to extract and such, like any archive reader. A good deal of software that convert PDF into other files achieve extracting almost all information of it right and transpose it into another type of file, so why not an archive reader? It's the same work without the conversion step, only reading one

Comment: There is another stack exchange site labeled "software recommendations" where you questions fits better. I have difficulties to understand what you are trying to achieve as I don't see any use in separating pictures from text for instance.

Comment: What is wrong with opening the PDF in any reader, such as Sumatra or PDF-XChange Editor. and copying any or all of it?

Comment: @r2d3 thanks, I'll do that; 

\@DrMoishePippik You generally can't copy of a PDF reader, you can hack by taking a screenshot or something. But I want the actual files stored in the PDF, the original ones, not just a scan of it

Answer (score 1):

I think you are refering to  [COS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49207768/what-does-cos-stand-for) viewers

iText call theirs [RUPS](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/rups)

in this case its [Adobe PreFlight](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/analyzing-documents-preflight-tool-acrobat.html)

[image]

Some are more graphic than others here is [one simple free viewer](https://www.o2sol.com/pdfxplorer/screenshots.htm) but I tend to use the one found in [Xchange PDF editor](https://help.tracker-software.com/pdfxe9/content-pane_ed.html), as it shows the target objects, but may need another to verify raw content.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's pretty much that I guess, if it has the extraction function then it's all good. Ideally to extract all into individual files like an archiver reader. Whatever the output file, I can convert them to something I like if necessary

Comment: About text encoding, it seems to be a challenge when you want to re-invent the wheel, but actually, there are plenty of readers and converters that achieve making legible such text. So why is it not possible to use the same method to get nice text? About encrypted things, I only work with not encrypted PDF, and if there is part encrypted, well, I can do without it, of find the password. About compressed things, always possible to uncompress, automatically or not

Comment: Yeah I get it, it's PS/GS legacy. But I mean, PDF viewer already done alllllll the work needed to uniformize it's content to display it in screen. It can even convert the file to other format, meaning it has understood all the content to write it in another format. So like I've said no need to recreate the wheel. The only thing that its needed is to think how those data to be cut to simulate a kind of uncompression, because gross one will give giberrish without its decryption key (like you've said, the font needed and so on...)